# Using an if statement to update OR insert into

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, statements

I have the following code which up dates my database table perfectly. However, I now wish it to either, update an existing row if the value of $status is 'open', or create a new row if the value of $status is 'completed'.

This is my code so far;

```
        <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit_update_activity'])); {
      require 'dbh.inc.php';
      $activity_id          =   $_POST['hidden_activity_id'];
      $idFromKnowledgeBase  =   $_POST['hidden_idFromKnowledgeBase'];
      $hiddenUserID         =   $_POST['hidden_userId'];
      $title                =   $_POST['title'];
      $description          =   $_POST['description'];
      $assigned_to          =   $_POST['assigned_to'];
      $category             =   $_POST['category'];
      $cost                 =   $_POST['cost'];
      $next_due             =   $_POST['next_due'];
      $due_every            =   $_POST['due_every'];
      $frequency            =   $_POST['frequency'];
      $supplier             =   $_POST['supplier'];
      $status               =   $_POST['status'];
      $comments             =   $_POST['comments'];
      $emptyAssignedTo      =   $_POST['empty_assigned_to'];
      $emptyStatus          =   $_POST['empty_status'];
      $emptyCategory        =   $_POST['empty_category'];
      $dateCompleted        =   $_POST['date_completed'];
      $emptyFrequency       =   $_POST['empty_frequency'];
      $emptyNextDue         =   $_POST['empty_next_due'];
      $next_due = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateCompleted. " + {$due_every} $frequency"));
      if (empty($frequency)) {
        $frequency = $emptyFrequency;
      }
      if (empty($status)) {
        $status = $emptyStatus;
      }
      if (empty($assigned_to)) {
        $assigned_to = $emptyAssignedTo;
      }
      if (empty($category)) {
        $category = $emptyCategory;
      }
      //This line isn't working
      if ($status == 'open') {
        $next_due = $emptyNextDue;
      } else {
        $next_due = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateCompleted. " + {$due_every} $frequency"));
      }
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE activities SET idFromKnowledgeBase = ?, userId = ?, title = ?, description = ?, assigned_to = ?, category = ?, cost = ?, last_completed = ?,next_due = ?, frequency = ?, supplier = ?, status = ?, comments = ? WHERE id = ?");
      $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssss", $idFromKnowledgeBase, $hiddenUserID, $title, $description, $assigned_to, $category, $cost, $dateCompleted, $next_due, $frequency, $supplier, $status, $comments, $activity_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      if($stmt->affected_rows >0) {
        header('Location: ../all_activities.php?updated');
      }
      }
      ?>
```

I've tried =, == and === for comparing $status.  If I take it back a notch and echo either 'open' or 'completed' depending on the value of $status, it works fine, echoing the correct answer each time.

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything there to insert a new row, you always attempt to UPDATE. Why not put the prepare / bind_param lines inside the else, and add a similar 2 lines in the if for an INSERT equivalent?

Comment: check what are u getting `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: "*I've tried =, == and ===*" , you cant use `=` assignment operator here assignment != comparing

Comment: I love the irony of explaining operators by using them in the explanation.

Comment: please explain properly where you are having a problem... you question is unclear

Comment: wouldn't it be more sensible to have a 'completed' field and just update the appropriate column? why do you want a whole new row with the same information?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the INSERT statement

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_update_activity'])); {
  require 'dbh.inc.php';
  $activity_id          =   $_POST['hidden_activity_id'];
  $idFromKnowledgeBase  =   $_POST['hidden_idFromKnowledgeBase'];
  $hiddenUserID         =   $_POST['hidden_userId'];
  $title                =   $_POST['title'];
  $description          =   $_POST['description'];
  $assigned_to          =   $_POST['assigned_to'];
  $category             =   $_POST['category'];
  $cost                 =   $_POST['cost'];
  $next_due             =   $_POST['next_due'];
  $due_every            =   $_POST['due_every'];
  $frequency            =   $_POST['frequency'];
  $supplier             =   $_POST['supplier'];
  $status               =   $_POST['status'];
  $comments             =   $_POST['comments'];
  $emptyAssignedTo      =   $_POST['empty_assigned_to'];
  $emptyStatus          =   $_POST['empty_status'];
  $emptyCategory        =   $_POST['empty_category'];
  $dateCompleted        =   $_POST['date_completed'];
  $emptyFrequency       =   $_POST['empty_frequency'];
  $emptyNextDue         =   $_POST['empty_next_due'];
  $next_due = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateCompleted. " + {$due_every} $frequency"));
  if (empty($frequency)) {
    $frequency = $emptyFrequency;
  }
  if (empty($status)) {
    $status = $emptyStatus;
  }
  if (empty($assigned_to)) {
    $assigned_to = $emptyAssignedTo;
  }
  if (empty($category)) {
    $category = $emptyCategory;
  }
  //This line isn't working
  if ($status == 'open') {
    $next_due = $emptyNextDue;
  } else {
    $next_due = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateCompleted. " + {$due_every} $frequency"));
  }
  if($status == 'completed') 
  {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO activities(idFromKnowledgeBase, userId, title , description, assigned_to, category, cost, last_completed,next_due, frequency, supplier , status, comments) VALUES(:kb, :uid, :title, :descr, :assign, :cat, :cost, :last, :next,  :freq, :sup, :stat, :com)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
      'kb' => $idFromKnowledgeBase,
      'uid' => $hiddenUserID, 
      'title' => $title, 
      'descr' => $description, 
      'assign' => $assigned_to, 
      'cat' => $category, 
      'cost' => $cost, 
      'last' => $dateCompleted, 
      'next' => $next_due, 
      'freq' => $frequency, 
      'sup' => $supplier, 
      'stat' => $status, 
      'com' => $comments, 
    ));
  }
  else 
  {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE activities SET idFromKnowledgeBase = :kb, userId = :uid, title = :title, description = :descr, assigned_to = :assign, category = :cat, cost = :cost, last_completed = :last,next_due = :next, frequency = :freq, supplier = :sup, status = :stat, comments = :com WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->execute(array(
      'kb' => $idFromKnowledgeBase,
      'uid' => $hiddenUserID, 
      'title' => $title, 
      'descr' => $description, 
      'assign' => $assigned_to, 
      'cat' => $category, 
      'cost' => $cost, 
      'last' => $dateCompleted, 
      'next' => $next_due, 
      'freq' => $frequency, 
      'sup' => $supplier, 
      'stat' => $status, 
      'com' => $comments, 
      'id' => $activity_id
    ));
  }
  if($stmt->affected_rows >0) {
    header('Location: ../all_activities.php?updated');
  }
  }
  ?>
```